# Jquery menu - How do i choose how many pixels it has to slide to the left

Tags: jquery

Hi I got this code that doesn't work completly like I want it to. My problem is that I can't choose min pixel it has to move too the left, when you press the #menu_btn. I've a element with a width on 65px where the rest of the menu is 165px, and i only want it to go 165px to the left, when i press the button so you still can press the button that is on the 65px. How would i do that?

```
  $('#menu_btn').on('click', function (){
        $('#menu_container').toggle('slide', { direction: 'left' }, 500);
    });
```

Also another problem I have is that the menu is open to start off with, i would like it to be "deactivated" first time you visit the site untill you click on the btn.

Comment: try setting a css style of min-width: 65px; to menu_container.

Comment: @Puzzle84 Didn't work :(

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle with what you' are trying to do? will help solve this issue for you

Comment: Thanks @Puzzle84 I got it working with this code: https://jsfiddle.net/f9ygwx13/

Comment: nice, glad you figured it out.